# Is there a global REQUEST handler for CodeIgniter or at least PHP like in Global.asax on ASP.NET?

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter

In ASP.NET I have the `Application_AcquireRequestState` method in `global.asax` so that I can handle all requests that hit my application, so then I can do some things like take care of cookies or URL segments or anything I want before execution of the controller code itself

Is there anything like that in PHP or in CI specially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [CodeIgniter Hooks](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html) - check out the `pre_system` and `pre_controller` action hooks in CodeIgniter. You could also opt to [extend core system classes](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html) if you're feeling particularly daring.

CodeIgniter is just a [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework with a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern), so you could always just modify `index.php` in the project root prior to when the CodeIgniter Bootstrap gets loaded. All application processes route through `index.php` (the front controller).

Comment: Thanks man, I picked the `pre_controller` approach and worked like a charm!